# CMake project with a static lib depending on another static lib

Tags: c++, cmake, build, linker, static-libraries

I have a project with the below structure. Basically, there are two static libraries: `lib_a` and `lib_b`. `lib_a` uses classes and functions defined in `lib_b`. There is the main executable, which depends on `lib_a` (and indirectly on `lib_b`), and unit tests for `lib_a`, which also indirectly depend on `lib_b`.

```
project
|--CMakeLists.txt
|--static_lib_a
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |--include
|  |  \--header_a.h
|  \--src
|     |--file_a.h
|     \--file_a.cpp
|--static_lib_b
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |--include
|  |  \--header_b.h
|  \--src
|     |--file_b.h
|     \--file_b.cpp
|--main_exe
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  \--main.cpp
\--unit_test
   |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--main.cpp
   \--test_lib_a.cpp
```

Since static libraries generally do not link with each other, both `main_exe` and `unit_test` need to link `lib_a` and `lib_b`. Is there a way to tell CMake that anything that links `lib_a` also needs to link with `lib_b`, without specifying this explicitly in `main_exe` and `unit_test`? That is, can I express this dependency in `static_lib_a/CMakeLists.txt` file?

What should be the content of each of the CMakeLists.txt file?

So far I have the following, which produces linking errors (that is, `lib_b` does not get linked to `unit_test`):

project/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(project)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(static_lib_a)
add_subdirectory(static_lib_b)
add_subdirectory(main_exe)
add_subdirectory(unit_test)
```

project/static_lib_a/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

add_library(lib_a STATIC)
target_sources(lib_a PRIVATE
    src/file_a.cpp)

target_include_directories(lib_a
    PUBLIC  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

target_link_libraries(lib_a lib_b)
```

project/static_lib_b/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

add_library(lib_b STATIC)
target_sources(lib_b PRIVATE
    src/file_b.cpp)

target_include_directories(lib_b
    PUBLIC  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```

main_exe/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

add_executable(main_exe)
target_sources(main_exe PRIVATE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main_exe PRIVATE lib_a)
```

unit_test/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

include(CTest)

add_executable(unit_test)
target_sources(unit_test PRIVATE
    main.cpp
    test_lib_a.cpp)
target_link_libraries(unit_test PRIVATE lib_a)

add_test(NAME unit_test COMMAND unit_test)
add_custom_target(run_unit_test ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -C debug --output-on-failure
    DEPENDS unit_test)
```

Comment: @drescherjm I added the line and it seems to work. Why didn't I think of this? Thanks!

Comment: `which produces linking errors` Please compile the project in verbose mode (`make VERBOSE=1` or `cmake --verbose`) and post all the errors verbatim with the compilation command. `that is, lib_b does not get linked to unit_test` Have you inspected the link command line? Please post it. `I added the line and it seems to work` Is the question solved?

Comment: "Is there a way to tell CMake that anything that links `lib_a` also needs to link with `lib_b`" - Calling `target_link_libraries(lib_a PUBLIC lib_b)` should be sufficient for that purpose (your code misses PUBLIC keyword).